# OAuth 2 with native windows app

Tags: windows, oauth, oauth-2.0

Newbie question for someone unfamiliar with developing native Windows apps.

I'm looking for any documentation to see how one would do OAuth with a native windows app.  It doesn't seem like [WinHttp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384263(v=vs.85).aspx) has documentation on this.  I couldn't find much through googling either.

Are there any standard / recommended MSFT libraries that implement the OAuth client?

The application in question is being developed in C++ if that helps

Answer (score 0):

The Qt Network Authorization library (in Qt 5.8 and above) provides an API that supports the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qoauth2authorizationcodeflow.html) flow for clients.  For native applications, it may be prudent to subclass with an implementation containing [PKCE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636) support.